# Multiple updates to React setState causes re render hell and blocking

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi on first connection to a web socket I receive a flurry of approximateley 100  **Indiviual** event responses back to back which are not part of a promise but which are handled one by one by the following, as the data is received

```
 handleValueStateChange = (event) => {
  const { controls } = this.state;
  let _controls = Object.entries(controls);
    for (let cont of _controls) {
        let states = cont[1].states;
            if (states) {
                let state = Object.entries(states);
                for (let [stateId, contUuid] of state) {
                    if (contUuid === event.uuid) {
                    controls[cont[0]].statesValue[stateId] = event.value; 
                    this.setState({ controls });                               
                    }
                }
            }
        }         
    }
```

After the initial flurry , the above will only be called three or four times minute, which causes no issue when then passing controls = {this.state.controls} as props to a child component.

However how can i adjust the above code to try and slow down the amount of times the controls state is updated in the inital flurry phase, as this causes the blocking of the child component due to constant re rendering.

Comment: You could try using `React.Memo` to memoize the child components and prevent them for running their own re-renders, assuming their props aren't changing. Otherwise, you could try implementing some sort of debounce. https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Comment: Thank you ,unfortunately all the child components will use a subset of controls, so props will change, so that rules out React.Memo but I will look into debounce as an way forward